# apex:actionSupport not working in apex:selectCheckboxes

Tags: actionsupport

Following is the VisualForce code snippet:

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!users}" layout="pageDirection">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onselect" action="{!checkSelectList}" reRender="Panel1"/>
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!userOptions}"/>
</apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

I have tried `onselect`, `onclick`, `onchange` events but nothing has triggered my apex class function `checkSelectList`.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing below.

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!users}" layout="pageDirection">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!userOptions}"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onselect" action="{!checkSelectList}" reRender="Panel1"/>
</apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

Please let us know if this has helped you out.

Thanks!

**Edit**
Check the below snippet

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="rectypesec" rendered="{!IF( Case.ContactId == NULL, false , IF(isUpdate,false,true))}">
        <apex:outputLabel value="Case Record Type"/>
        <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRecType}" id="rectypeid" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!recTypeOption}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!GetTypeValues}" reRender="mainPage" status="loadingStatus2"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:actionStatus id="loadingStatus2">
        <apex:facet name="start">
        <apex:image url="/img/loading.gif" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" />
           </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
       </apex:actionRegion>
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="rectypesec2" rendered="{!IF(isUpdate,true,false)}">
         <apex:outputLabel value="Case Record Type"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!caseObj.RecordTypeId}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Nop. Nothing happened! I'll post my controller function too below:


`public PageReference checkSelectList()
    {
     System.debug('Selected-------------');
     Selection1=selections[0];
     return null;
    }`

Comment: it is not even calling the controller function so esentially actionSupport is not working.

Comment: Any reason that you have used **apex:selectcheckboxes** in V.f page here ? What kind of value are you passing in **!Users** ? Can you post a bit more part of your code.

Comment: All the users in that particular salesforce organization. Anyways the selectCheckboxes are working fine. Does actionSupport work with selectCheckboxes? Which components are supported by actionSupport?

Comment: I have used **apex:selectList** with actionsupport. It works perfectly fine. Try taking the users in the list once. See if it works

Comment: Could you post the code snippets here of your working code? I tried with selectList too but same result. Nothing happens. I have a feeling that I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: Added the code in the answer.

Comment: nop. I have used it with selectList in another page and that worked fine too but here it isn't working at all. So I'm missing something else. On this page I have more than one selectCheckboxes components. Does that make any difference?